# uniqueness in an array datatype in psql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unique, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with the following structure:-

```
uniq_id           | integer | not null default nextval('#########'::regclass)
user_id           | integer | not null
team_type         | text[]  |
```

I have a unique index on user_id and team_type.

The column team_type will have values like 'R' and 'F'.
for instance ,for a user_id 1234,I have a team type inserted {R,F}.i do not want anyone to insert {R} for the same user.

One more example for my requirements:
If user_id 1234 has **2** entries as {R} **AND** {F}, I do not want anyone to insert a record as {R,F} for the same user.

I am in need of a constraint or unique index which can do this for me.
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: I think you need a trigger here. not constaint as you need to check between several possible rows

Comment: Insert Trigger v/s Insert Rule?